# Request processing JSF lifecycle, only if the component tree was previously saved

Tags: jsf

Indeed, very less has been written/shed on the *component tree* itself, that seems to be source for a whole lot of problems when one takes on understanding JSF.

One of the quote I recently read on a social networking site-

*LIBRARY - Because not everything on the Internet is true.*

Neither the above nor its opposite holds true either.

This is a screenshot from **Anghel Leonard's book- Mastering Java Server Faces 2.2**

[image]

I think this is plainly wrong. The author seems to be confused **on whether its the component tree that gets saved** OR **the states of the components in the view(tree of UI components)**

Considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used) thread by BalusC-

> When the form is submitted and the view is restored, the JSF
>   component tree is just rebuilt from scratch and all binding attributes
>   will just be re-evaluated like described in above paragraph. After the
>   component tree is recreated, JSF will restore the **JSF view state into
>   the component tree**.

[image]

Don't forget to read the comments.

Nonetheless, I would love to clarify the above note. Is my understanding perfectly correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *... only if the component tree was previously saved ...*

This is indeed not specific enough. How it really should read is:

> ... only if the non-transient state of the component tree was previously saved ...

Comment: By non-transient, you mean serialized. Right.